# Is !obj[key] a good practice to check the existence of an object's property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties, hasownproperty, truthiness

Every now and then, I see this pattern:

```
if (!obj[key]) {
    // key does not exist inside object
    obj[key] = ...
} else {
    // maybe do something else with obj[key]
}
```

but I find it extremely wrong. What if actually obj[key] has the value `false` or `''` ?
Then the code doesn't make any sense to me.

Is there a reason I see this so often ? Why people don't use `.hasOwnProperty()` to check whether or not a `key` exists as a property of an object ?

Comment: Checking the property value is fast. It can be used when you can be sure the data doesn't contain falsy values. `.hasOwnProperty()` is slow, you can use `in` operator too.

Comment: @Teemu Is ```key in obj``` equivalent to ```obj[key] === undefined``` ?

Comment: In some cases you could also use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: @but-why No, `'a' in ({a: undefined})` is `true` whereas `({a: undefined})['a'] !== undefined` is `false`. (Assuming you meant `!==` instead of `===`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `in` operator:

```
"key" in obj // true, regardless of the actual value
```

if you want to particularly test for properties of the object instance (and not inherited properties), use hasOwnProperty:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty("key") // true
```

For performance comparison between the methods that are in, hasOwnProperty and key is undefined, check this [reference](https://jsben.ch/WqlIl)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if you are checking if the `key` prop exists, then definitely should no use it, there are better options, for example `.hasOwnProperty` or the `in` operator, for example:

```
const obj = { a: '' }

console.log('is key a in obj?', obj.hasOwnProperty('a'))
>>> true
console.log('is key a in obj?', 'a' in obj)
>>> true
console.log('is key a in obj?', Boolean(obj['a']))
>>> false // it's wrong, like u mentioned

console.log('is key b in obj', obj.hasOwnProperty('b'))
>>> false
console.log('is key b in obj', 'b' in obj)
>>> false
console.log('is key b in obj', Boolean(obj['b']))
>>> false
```